# best practice for creating table headings in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

The official `openpyxl` document suggests creating table headings this way:

```py
table = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(ref="C4:G5", displayName="Table1")
headings = ["Fruit", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"]
table._initialise_columns()
for column, value in zip(table.tableColumns, headings):
    column.name = value
```

However, by the convention `_initialise_columns()` is not a public method, we shouldn't call it directly from outside scope. So, I came up with this:

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws["C4"] = "Fruits"
ws["D4"] = "2011"
ws["E4"] = "2012"
ws["F4"] = "2013"
ws["G4"] = "2014"

table = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName="Table1", ref="C4:G5")
ws.add_table(table)

# wb.save("/tmp/table.xlsx")

print(table.tableColumns)
```

I noticed that the `print` gives an empty list `[]` without calling `save`, but calling it requires the file path to be known prior time. One can use `tmp` directory like the one in example code, or pass an IO object to it like this: `wb.save(io.BytesIO())`. I don't know which practice I should take, maybe there's an even better alternative?

Comment: You can pass in column headings explicitly. This is difficult to get right because it's a design fault in Excel which requires the headings to match the cells exactly, which is why we try and do it for you.